# The type or namespace name 'SortedSet' could not be found

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use SortedSet in a simple console application (using .NET 4.7.2) but for some reason it is not contained in `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

That being said HashSet is there and works perfectly fine.
According to documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=netframework-4.7.2) they're both in the same namespace, so I'm completely lost why one is there and the other isn't. If anyone has any suggestions I'd be glad to try them.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TextProcessor
{
    class App
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();
            SortedSet<string> sortedset = new SortedSet<string>();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: example code please

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. You have the right namespace.

Comment: Looks to me like you have it right there. What's the problem?

Comment: I just created new project and for some reason it works just fine. I have no idea what's wrong with my current project since it's pretty much clean with two classes. I think I'll just delete this question. Thank for help.

Comment: Did you delete the reference to System.dll?

Comment: No, I just started project as "Empty project" instead of "Console Application". Now that I checked "Console Application" has quite a few references that the "Empty Project" doesn't have. That must have been the reason. Thanks for answer.